# Multi-Table User Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I am currently developing a Student Information System that is going to be used by educational group to provide students & teachers a portal.

I am using Laravel4 which has a good authentication driver built in but can use only one table for authentication. I am unable to figure out how to authenticate them because I have users in multiple tables. Example :

- SchoolOne_students
- SchoolOne_teachers
- SchoolTwo_students
- SchoolTwo_teachers
  and so on....

Comment: Split up your tables. Have one for students, one for teachers then one for the schools and cross-reference them.

Answer (score 1):

A significantly better way, rather than multiple users tables, would be to link each user to their school and status (teacher or student). You certainly can twist Laravel into doing what you want, but in order to prevent conflicts between the four different user types, you'll probably end up having to rewrite a large part of the entire authentication package.

What I would do is, in your users table, have an `ENUM` column, with the options `student` and `teacher`. Then, have an integer column, `school_id` (with a separate table for school data, if needed). This will allow much more flexibility, and when your design requirements change (yes, they *will* change), you'll be able to take them in stride.

Using this method, you should not have to modify any of Laravel's own code.

Comment: Thank you but how do you propose I enter the details. I was going to bulk upload data which does not seem very possible here.

Answer (score 0):

if all the tables have identical schemas, you could create a view that does a `UNION` of all the tables and then use that view as your Laravel auth table.  I am not saying this is an ideal solution, but if you have restrictions on altering the existing tables and *must* use them as is, this could work.

The view would not be update-able (I don't believe so, at least) so adding or updating users would require specific add/update code, but for Auth, this may do the trick.

```
CREATE VIEW users_combined_view
AS
SELECT id, username, password 
FROM schoolOne_students
UNION
SELECT id, username, password
FROM schoolOne_teachers
UNION
...
```

**note** - this method would be somewhat useless (ok, totally useless) if `username` was not unique across the tables

Comment: Alas ! We do not have unique usernames for the tables. Its their emloyee id (teachers) and admission number (students) that server the purpose of username table. Also I do not have any table restriction as I am just to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

A good database design is scalable.
This is particularly a bad idea:

`SchoolOne_students
SchoolOne_teachers
SchoolTwo_students
SchoolTwo_teachers and so on...`

There should be only one table for all the users, in your case for `students`.

There should be another table for `Schools` where all the school information will be stored.

Then you should join the `students` table with `schools` table  by adding a `school_id` field to the `schools` table where the `school_id` will be stored for the corresponding students row.

```
    ===Students Table===
```

`+-----------------------------------------
 + id |  name  |school_id | ... | ... |
 +----+--------+----------+-----------+----
 + 1  |Student1|     5    | ... | ... |
 +----+--------+----------+-----------+----
 + 2  |Student1|     3    | ... | ... |`

```
    ===Schools Table===
```

`+-----------------------------------------
 + id |  name  | ... | ... | ... |
 +----+--------+----------+-----------+----
 + 3  |School 3| ... | ... | ... |
 +----+--------+----------+-----------+----
 + 5  |School 5| ... | ... | ... |
 +----+--------+----------+-----------+----`

This way you can add as many schools as you may want and students for them

I hope this will help